# Input & Print at the same time?(python 3.11, windows11)

Tags: python, terminal, curses, python-curses

Currently, the code waits for user input before printing the next number. I want the code to print numbers continuously without being interrupted by user input, but still allow the user to enter a number and have it displayed in the output. How can I do this?

```py
import time
for i in range(0,100000):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
    input('Enter: ')
```

i found this code
[Print and input at the same time python multithread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299399/print-and-input-at-the-same-time-python-multithread)

```py
import curses

history = []
def pprint(text):
    global history
    history.insert(0, text)
    if len(history) == int(curses.LINES) - 2:
        history = history[:int(curses.LINES) - 3]
    quote_window.clear()
    for his in history[::-1]:
        quote_window.addstr(his + "\n")
        quote_window.refresh()

stdscr = curses.initscr()

curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(True)
curses.curs_set(0)

if curses.has_colors():
    curses.start_color()

curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)

stdscr.addstr("Server", curses.A_REVERSE)
stdscr.chgat(-1, curses.A_REVERSE)

quote_window = curses.newwin(curses.LINES-2, curses.COLS, 1, 0)
input_window = curses.newwin(curses.LINES, curses.COLS, curses.LINES-1, 0)
input_window.bkgd(curses.color_pair(1))
input_window.addstr(">> ")
stdscr.noutrefresh()
quote_window.noutrefresh()
input_window.noutrefresh()

curses.doupdate()

comm = ""
while True:
    key = input_window.getch()
    if key == 10:
        pprint(comm)
        input_window.clear()
        input_window.addstr(">> ")
        comm = ""
    else:
        input_window.addstr(chr(key))
        comm += chr(key)

curses.nocbreak()
curses.echo()
curses.curs_set(1)
curses.endwin()
```

which works wonderfully and the ui looks really great but i cant copy i cant paste i cant backspace it does some weird characters is there some way to fix this code or new code that has the same ui look?

Answer (score 0):

You're right about how you can [open a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python) and use that to print numbers continually. Simply move the code that prints numbers into a function and put that in a separate thread, so that it runs concurrently with your other code that waits for the user's input.

This is an example implementation of the above concept.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def outputNumbers():
    for i in range(0,100000):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

thread = Thread(target = outputNumbers)
thread.start()

input('Enter: ')
# Other code separate to counting thread here
```

Comment: Enter: 0
hi1
2
ok3

 4
5
6
7
8
i said i want Enter to be below the numbers at all times